# Media queries for landscape printing?

Tags: css, printing, media-queries

I've got some styles specifically for print, which are being applied correctly with a print media query. The thing is, my layout breaks a bit if you switch to landscape printing, and I'd like to tweak some things for it. Is there any way to define styles for landscape printing?

Comment: Did you try the `(orientation: landscape)` media query in combination with `print`?

Comment: Wow, well no, I hadn't tried that for some reason. Works like a charm. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Media Queries offer matching against the device's orientation:

```
@media print and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* landscape styles */
}

@media print and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* portrait styles */
}
```

Comment: Does work in chrome, at least in the version I'm testing in.

Comment: Unfortunatly, This is not working in the current version of Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

```
<style>
    @media print {
        @page {
            size: landscape; /*automatically set to Landscape only*/
        }
    }
</style>
```

If you want letting the user to choose between the two ways : portrait/Landscape, do :

```
 <style type="text/css" media="print">
        @page {
            /* portrait/Landscape */
            size: auto;
           /*adding some margins to let the title and the date to be displayed*/
            margin: 40px 10px 35px; 
        }
  </style>
```