# Format style of page printed in landscape mode via SCSS

Tags: javascript, css, angular, sass, scss-mixins

I have an application that has lots of tabes that get cut off when a user tries to print it in landscape mode (portrait mode prints fine).  As such, is there any way I can change the styles of a page for only when a user prints the document in landscape mode (via print prompt).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Landscape printing from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138422/landscape-printing-from-html)

Comment: No, that simply directs your application to be printed in landscape mode.  I want the styles of my application to dynamically change depending on whether it is being printed in portrait vs landscape mode.

Comment: There was an answer on that question (that wasn't the accepted), but you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596982/media-queries-for-landscape-printing

Comment: I was hoping for a solution just like the one mentioned.  Unfortunately, that does not work in modern Chrome or Safari.