# check page orientation while printing

Tags: html, css, laravel

I am new to css and i want to check for page orientation while printing I wrote this code but it's not working

```
        @media print {
            /* if the page orientation is landscape */
            @media (orientation: landscape) {
                .card {
                    background-color: 'green';
                }
            }

            /* else if the page orientation is portrait*/

            @media (orientation: portrait) {
                .card {
                    background-color: 'yellow';
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Media queries for landscape printing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596982/media-queries-for-landscape-printing)

Comment: thanks for the link but i I already saw this question it's not working

Comment: Did you try `@media print {/* set the page size to landscape */ @page {size: landscape;}` ?

Comment: not yet i will check now

Comment: this will set the page to landscape but I want the user should be able to change the orientation of the page