How to make html table in landscape mode bigger for pdfs
So I am creating some html tables for pdfs and I am trying to make sure when it is defaulted to landscape mode. So I was thinking of maybe putting it 90 degrees or putting it sideways. When it gets printed it is still going to print in an a4 format but landscape.
I tried using transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%); to rotate it 90 degrees but it just doesn't look right it cuts off when it is in portrait format and it is still in portrait format but it is just a lot bigger.
    <style>
        body, html {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;  /* Avoids any scrollbars from appearing */
            width: 210mm;  /* Set the width to the height of an A4 page */
            height: 297mm; /* Set the height to the width of an A4 page */
        }
        @page {
            size: A4 landscape;
            margin: 0; /* Removes default margins set by the browser */
        }
        .specific-table-container {
            position: relative;  /* Relative positioning to facilitate rotation */
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            transform-origin: 0 0; /* Sets the rotation pivot to the top left corner */
            transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%); /* Rotates the container -90 degrees */
            transform-style: preserve-3d; /* Preserves 3D when transforming */
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
        table {
            width: 297mm; /* Switched dimensions to fill the rotated container */
            height: 210mm;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        th, td {
            border: 1px solid #666;
            padding: 5px; /* Reduced padding to accommodate more content */
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 12px; /* Adjust font size based on readability */
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        th {
            font-weight: bold;
        }
        tr:nth-child(odd) {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even) {
            background-color: #ffffff;
        }
    </style>```


Take a look at media query orientation to detect orientation of viewport may be in combination with the print media type. Here's a question that asks exactly about this here ➡️ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596982/media-queries-for-landscape-printing

May be also take a look at (page-orientation)[https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/page-orientation] if you want to explicitly specify page orientation when printing.
